# Bad Request when making a call to a REST WCF WebService

Tags: android, json, web-services, wcf, rest

I'm writing an Android application and a WCF REST service to call from it. When I try to make a call to a certain method I receive an "Bad Request" message. In a previous test I managed to do this call and its worked, but after some changes in classes I could not again.

This is the classes in the service:

```
public class Venda
    {
        public int Cod { get; set; }
        public string Pedido { get; set; }
        public int Cliente { get; set; }
        public int Vendedor { get; set; }
        public string Modo { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public double Total { get; set; }
        public string Observacoes { get; set; }
        public string TipoPagto { get; set; }
        public double Desconto { get; set; }
        public int ST { get; set; }
        public int GF { get; set; }

        public List<DetalheVenda> DetalhesVenda { get; set; }

        public Venda()
        {
            DetalhesVenda = new List<DetalheVenda>();
        }
    }

public class DetalheVenda
    {
        public int Cod { get; set; }
        public string Pedido { get; set; }
        public string Produto { get; set; }
        public double Quantidade { get; set; }
        public double ValorVenda { get; set; }
        public double ValorCompra { get; set; }
        public double ValorVendaMinimo { get; set; }
        public int ST { get; set; }
        public double Desconto { get; set; }
        public int Vendedor { get; set; }
        public int Cliente { get; set; }
        public string Modo { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public string Grade { get; set; }
        public string SubGrade { get; set; }
    }
```

Method interface and implementation:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "AdicionaVenda",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        void AdicionaVenda(Venda venda);


 //a breakingpoint nor enter here
public void AdicionaVenda(Venda venda)
        {
            repositorio.AdicionaVenda(venda);
        }
```

This is the JSON that I send as the body request:
{"venda":
    {"Cod":null,"Pedido":"1.1.56","Cliente":0,"Vendedor":1,"Modo":"A prazo","Data":"2014-02-22","Total":0,"Observacoes":"","TipoPagto":"Tipo Teste","Desconto":0,"ST":1,"GF":0,
    "DetalhesVenda":[{"Cod":null,"Pedido":"1.1.56","Produto":"13","Quantidade":0,"ValorVenda":9,"ValorCompra":5,"ValorVendaMinimo":0,"ST":0,"Desconto":0,"Vendedor":0,"Cliente":0,"Modo":"A prazo","Data":"2014-02-22","Grade":"grade 1","SubGrade":"subgrade 1"}]}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its not a problem with `DateTime` filed in your model classes but it is something from .NET.

There is [no standard JSON format of Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format).This is why you are facing this problem. There are two solutions for this:

1. Use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json).
2. Or, set the type of your date to `String` in model class and later on when you receive json, parse it into `DateTime`.

See these links:

[The Right JSON Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159097/wcf-client-how-can-i-deserialize-an-incompatible-date-format-from-the-json-respo) and [Incompatible date format in JSON from response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159097/wcf-client-how-can-i-deserialize-an-incompatible-date-format-from-the-json-respo).

Comment: Yes, I did the second option.

Comment: I was also following the same approach :)

Answer (score 0):

I discover that problem is the DateTime new fields in model classes of service.